# Help with proof by induction, please! I may not be understanding how to work with factorials.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction

> Prove that for all integers $n \ge 1, 1\cdot1! + 2\cdot2! + 3\cdot3! + \cdots + n\cdot n! = (n+1)! - 1$.

OK, so I verified base case $n = 1: 2! - 1 = 1$

I assumed that for all $k \ge n, P(k) = (k+1)! - 1$

I am unsure how to prove true for $P(k+1)$, though I understand that the first step is to replace all $k$ values with $k+1$ which yields $$1\cdot1! + 2\cdot2! + 3\cdot3! + \cdots + k!\cdot k! + (k+1\cdot k+1)! = (k+2)! - 1$$

What next?

Comment: I recommend reading [How to write a clear induction proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1253956/proof-writing-how-to-write-a-clear-induction-proof).

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Note that each term $k\times k!=(k+1)!-k!$

Comment: As for your induction step, begin with just the left side, use a chain of equalities to make it eventually equal your intended right hand side, using your induction hypothesis along the way.  $(1\cdot 1!+2\cdot 2!+\dots + k\cdot k!) + (k+1)\cdot (k+1)! = \color{blue}{(k+1)!}-1 + (k+1)\cdot \color{blue}{(k+1)!} = \cdots$  Now, notice that what I colored blue is equal and so may be combined as like terms.

Answer (score 5):

If you are working with proofs by induction, then you have (hopefully) dealt with $\Sigma$-notation for making sums more manageable. In my experience, it also makes proofs by induction with sums easier to cobble together and understand (see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1189076/191378) for one such reason).

Now, at the possible risk of oversimplifying some things, you've got the base case down. You get to assume or make the inductive hypothesis (for $k\geq1$) that

$$
1\cdot1!+2\cdot2!+\cdots+k\cdot k!=\color{blue}{\sum_{i=1}^k i\cdot i!}=\color{blue}{(k+1)!-1}.\tag{1}
$$

Using the base case and the assumption (i.e., inductive hypothesis) stated in $(1)$, your goal is to then show that

$$
\color{green}{\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}i\cdot i!} = \color{green}{(k+2)!-1}\tag{2}
$$

naturally follows. And we can do this in the following manner:

\begin{align}
\color{green}{\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}i\cdot i!}
&= \color{blue}{\sum_{i=1}^ki\cdot i!} + \underbrace{(k+1)\cdot(k+1)!}_{\substack{\text{evaluate}\\\text{sum at $k=i+1$}}}\\[1em]
&= \underbrace{[\color{blue}{(k+1)!-1}]}_{\substack{\text{use inductive}\\\text{hypothesis from $(1)$}}} + (k+1)(k+1)!\\[1em]
&= (k+1)!-1+(k+1)(k+1)! & \text{(simplify)}\\[1em]
&= (k+1)![1+(k+1)]-1 & \text{(rearrange and factor out $(k+1)!$)}\\[1em]
&= (k+1)!(k+2)-1 & \text{(simplify)}\\[1em]
&= \color{green}{(k+2)!-1}. & \text{(by definition of factorial)}
\end{align}
Since we have shown what we set out to show, namely that $(2)$ follows from the base case and the assumption of $(1)$, we can call it a day. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

You don't really need induction here (or an obvious use of induction) since you have
$$(k+1)!=(k+1)\cdot k!= k\cdot k!+k!\iff k\cdot k!= (k+1)!- k!$$
for all $k$, so that you obtain a telescoping sum.

Comment: Well, induction is substituted here by the telescoping (they have the same idea)

Comment: @richrow: Behind telescoping, there is indeed induction, but it is so well-known that usually, one doesn't even mention it.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. Just wanted to say that this another form (maybe clearer) of induction.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:  If $f(n) = 1*1! + 2*2! + ..... + n*n!$ then $f(n+1) = 1*1! + 2*2! + ..... + n*n! + (n+1)(n+1)! = f(n) + (n+1)(n+1)!$.

Hint 2:   $m!(m+1) = (m+1)!$ and $m!*m + m! {=\over{\text{factor}}} m!(m+1) = m!(m+1)= m!$.

> So if we assume $f(k) = 1*1! + 2*2! + ..... + k*k!= (k+1)! - 1$.

.

> Then $f(k+1) = f(k) + (k+1)(k+1)! =$

.

> $(k +1)! -1 +  (k+1)(k+1)!=(k+1)! + (k+1)(k+1)! - 1 = (k+1)![1+(k+1)]-1=$

.

> $(k+1)![k+2]-1 = (k+2)!-1$

Answer (score 2):

Assume $P(n-1)$:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k\cdot k!=n!-1
$$
Add $n\cdot n!$ to both sides:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^nk\cdot k!
&=n\cdot n!+n!-1\\
&=(n+1)n!-1\\[9pt]
&=(n+1)!-1
\end{align}
$$
and we have $P(n)$.

Answer (score 2):

After first step which you mentioned,We have

=>1.1!+2.2!+3.3!+.......+n.n!+(n+1)(n+1)!

As a second step,put the value of expression 
1.1!+2.2!+3.3!+..........n.n! which is equal to (n+1)!-1 from original equation to step 1. The expression will then become

= (n+1)!-1+(n+1)(n+1)!

=(n+1)!(1+n+1)-1

=(n+1)!(n+2)-1

=(n+2)!-1

=((n+1)+1)!-1

Answer (score 1):

OK, so we're trying to show here that

$\displaystyle  \sum_1^n j\cdot j! = (n + 1)! - 1, \tag 1$

and we want to use induction to do it.  Our OP algebrahman correctly verified the case $n = 1$, so we can accept that as a starting point without further ado.

Now if we assume the existence of some $k$ such that

$\displaystyle  \sum_1^k j\cdot j! = (k + 1)! - 1, \tag 2$

we merely need add $(k + 1) (k + 1)!$ to each side to obtain

$\displaystyle  \sum_1^{k + 1} j\cdot j! = \sum_1^k j\cdot j! + (k + 1)(k + 1)!$
$= (k + 1)! + (k + 1) (k + 1)! -  1  = ((k + 1) + 1) (k + 1)! - 1$
$= (k + 2) (k + 1)! - 1 =  (k + 2)! - 1,  \tag 3$

and we are ***done!!!***

***Note Added in Edit, Thursday 6 February 2020 12:22 PM PST:*** A few thoughts about our OP's proof attempt:  one can't simply replace $k$ by $k + 1$ and expect the resulting formula to bind; *that* is in fact what we are trying to prove; rather, one needs to use the ordinary rules of arithmetic and algebra to perform the addition of $(k + 1)(k + 1)$ to each side of (2), as was done here.  ***End of Note.***

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, if $n=1$, this amount consists of a single sum, which is $1\cdot 1!=1$ and which coincides with $(1+1)!-1$.

If $n$ is such a natural number that $n\geq 1$ and the induction hypothesis is assumed to be true for $n$, that is to say, if 
    $$\sum_{k=1}^n k\cdot k!=(n+1)!-1,$$
    then that hypothesis is also true for $n+1$, that is to say,
    $$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}k\cdot k!=(n+2)!-1,$$
    so
    $$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}k\cdot k!=\sum_{k=1}^n k\cdot k!+(n+1)\cdot (n+1)!\underbrace{=}_{\text{induction hypothesis}}(n+1)!-1+(n+1)\cdot (n+1)!=(1+n+1)\cdot (n+1)!-1=(n+2)!-1$$
    and the test is, by the principle of induction, concluded.